# Highcharts -- show axis labels on extreme edges

Tags: javascript, highcharts

At times the labels aren't showing up on the extreme edges of an axis.  For example, in this picture I would always like a label at the top of the chart, like where that red circle is (as well as near the origin).  Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: can't see any images here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Believe it or not, Highcharts has the following property [`yAxis.showLastLabel`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.showLastLabel) and it's default value is `false` (even though the documentation says the default is `true`).

This has screwed me over more than once. Set it to `true` and you're good to go.

```
{
  yAxis: {
    showLastLabel: true
  }
}
```